# Passing Location from remote machine to more than one machine only once

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, invoke-command

1. I have a script `C:\code.ps1` on multiple machine, say A, B, C.

   `code.ps1` is something like below

   ```
   $path = Read-Host "Provide path name"
   $AbsolutePath = "$path\somefile"
   ```
2. when you run `code.ps1` it ask for the user input for some location before going further execution.
3. As I need to run code.ps1 on multiple machine parallel, I decided to run it from a single remote machine, say D, like below:

   ```
   $comp = @('A','B','C')
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $comp -ScriptBlock {C:\code.ps1}
   ```
4. It is running good for A, B, C but problem is that I need to provide the user input 3 times (here 3 machine A, B, C) as when we run `code.ps1` it ask for user input for a location.

How can we fix this so that running this script from machine D will only ask for user input only once irrespective of no. of machined on which `code.ps1` is there.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the location is the same on all remote hosts you should be able to get the path inside the scriptblock via the `using:` scope classifier.

```bsh
$Location = Read-Host -Prompt "Input location for the installer"
$Machine  = @('A','B')
Invoke-Command -Computer $Machine -ScriptBlock {& "$using:Location\install.msi"}
```

You could also pass the path into the scriptblock as an argument:

```bsh
$Location = Read-Host -Prompt "Input location for the installer"
$Machine  = @('A','B')
Invoke-Command -Computer $Machine -ScriptBlock {
    Param($Installer)
    & "$Installer"
} -ArgumentList "$Location\install.msi"
```

Either way put the path in double quotes to take care of spaces in it, and use the call operator to execute the command string.

If the paths differ from machine to machine you need to invoke the commands as separate jobs per machine. Prompting on the remote machine doesn't work, because the invoked command isn't running in an interactive session.

Comment: I want to use the first one you provided. 
Can I use 
Invoke-Command -Computer $Machine -ScriptBlock {& "$using:Location"}
without providing .msi name - as msi name may be diff in future ?

Comment: Sure, you can just as well do `& "$using:Pathtoexec"` as long as the path is the same on all machines.

Comment: Thank You. I will test in realtime in few minutes and will update here .

Comment: Actaully looks like I asked question in some confusing way . I just edited few things. Can you please check if some time. Actually code.ps1 is the code that is getting executed - When we run this it will ask for path of msi. But it will ask again and again for every machine that has code.ps1

Comment: location of msi will asked only when we execute code.ps1 (it's available on all machine)- That's my problem . And for all machine it will ask  as inside code.ps1 it is like that . Can we do something like that when we run code.ps1 from remote machine _ it will ask for the location of msi----Any way to put the msi location only once and can be used y all code.ps1 on all mahcine ? I know it's going bit lengthy but this is my actual problem.

Comment: Please re-read the last paragraph in my answer. You can't do it like this, because in the remote session there's nothing that could respond to the script prompting for input.

Comment: I believe I explained problem in not a good way. I just update one question with step by step things >>

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39448818/passing-location-while-running-script-remotely-powershell   Can you please have a look if time permits.

Comment: Please do not re-post questions. Edit (improve) the current question if you think that your code/explanation was incomplete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123152/discussion-between-rishua-and-ansgar-wiechers).